# Transformation of the Black-Scholes PDE into the diffusion equation - shift of coordinate system

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mathematical-finance

The aim of transforming the Black-Scholes PDE is of course to find a form where an relatively easy solution exists. Most of the steps seem to be straightforward - please use this reference:
https://planetmath.org/AnalyticSolutionOfBlackScholesPDE

...all but one, actually the last one where a convection-diffusion equation is being transformed into the basic diffusion equation.

[In the article you find it here: "Under the new coordinate system (z), we have the relations amongst vector fields ... leading to the following transformation of equation..."]

The u_x-term vanishes by some magic coordinate transformation. When you look at the derivatives they even seems wrong to me because they state that tau=s and then derive delta/delta tau = delta/delta s + some extra term (delta/delta y * -(r-1/2 sigma^2).

I simply don't get it: first how it works and second how they find that kind of transformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the Planetmath page put my browser into an infinite reload loop, so I can't help you with the formalism there.

I would recommend instead looking at the change of variables in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-Scholes#Derivation).  The last time I checked it, it seemed to work.

**Edit:**  Okay, I have a formulation that works.  I'll write s for sigma, so the equation is initially:

V<sub>t</sub> + (1/2)s<sup>2</sup>S<sup>2</sup>V<sub>SS</sub> = rV - rSV<sub>S</sub>.

Since S follows a lognormal random walk (in particular the stochastic diff eq governing S involves a logarithmic derivative), it is natural to change to x = log S, or S = e<sup>x</sup>, so the log price x follows normal Brownian motion.  This yields the equation:

V<sub>t</sub> + (1/2)s<sup>2</sup>(V<sub>xx</sub> - V<sub>x</sub>) = r(V - V<sub>x</sub>).

Black-Scholes is a final-value problem, i.e., we know the value of the option at time T, and diffusion works backwards.  It is therefore natural to negate the time variable (and multiply by a suitable scalar to make things neater).  tau = (1/2)s<sup>2</sup>(T-t).  Then we get:

(1/2)s<sup>2</sup>(V<sub>xx</sub> - V<sub>x</sub> - V<sub>tau</sub>) = r(V - V<sub>x</sub>).

Finally we rescale the value function to remove exponential growth effects.  u = e<sup>ax + b(tau)</sup>V for undetermined coefficients a and b.  We can substitute, multiply the equation by 2e<sup>ax+b(tau)</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>, and we get:

u<sub>xx</sub> + (something)u<sub>x</sub> + (something else)u = u<sub>tau</sub>.

(something) is a degree one polynomial in a and is independent of b.  (something else) is a degree one polynomial in b, so we can choose a and b to kill those terms.  This yields the diffusion equation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Scott - anyway it is the same thing here: x=ln(S/K)+(r-sigma^2/2)*tau - I don't understand how you come to this term and how the actual transformation works.

p.s.: you are right, there are some browser problems with this site, IE works well though

Comment: I got this solution from Strang's <i>Computational Science and Engineering</i>, which references <i>The Mathematics of Financial Derivatives</i> by Wilmott, Harrison, and Dewynne.

Comment: Scott: Thank you very much, again! Could you please elaborate on this part: "we get:
uxx + (something)ux + (something else)u = utau.
(something) is a degree one polynomial in a and is independent of b. (something else) is a degree one polynomial in b, so we can choose a and b to kill those terms. "

Could you please give an example for "something" and "something else" so that these terms vanish?

Comment: If you work it out, you get:
(something) = 2r/s^2 - 1 - 2a, so you can set a = r/s^2 - 1/2 to make it vanish.
(something else) = a^2/s^2 - 2ar/s^2 + a - 2r/s^2 + b, so you can set b = 2r/s^2 + 2ar/s^2 - a - a^2/s^2 to make it vanish.